# Undefined/Null value using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get some data from Facebook graph but I'm having a little problem. It appears that the second request works fine (checked that using the commented console line) but when I get the response2 value and store it in myEvents array,  I try to print that value but it shows null.

```
 FB.api('me/events?fields=id,location', function(response) {

                    for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {

                        myEvents[i] = new Array(3);

                        myEvents[i][0]= response.data[i].id;
                        myEvents[i][1]= response.data[i].location;


                        //get number of attending people per event
                        var q = response.data[i].id+'/attending';
                        FB.api(q, function(response2) {

                            //console.log(response2.data.length); //check response
                            myEvents[i][2]=response2.data.length; //asign response value to array



                        });

                        console.log(myEvents[i][2]); //here show null instead of the assigned value
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `FB.api` does not halt execution. Closures, like event handlers, provide ways to handle asynchronous operations. Let's look at your code again.

```js
FB.api( 'me/events?fields=id,location',
  function(response) {
    // This code is executed once the outer async FB.api call (me/events) completes

    for ( var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++ ) {
      myEvents[i] = new Array(3);
      myEvents[i][0]= response.data[i].id;
      myEvents[i][1]= response.data[i].location;

      console.log( "Log A" );

      var q = response.data[i].id+'/attending';

      FB.api( q,
        function( response2 ) {
          // This code is executed once the inner async FB.api call (id/attending) completes

          myEvents[i][2]=response2.data.length;

          console.log( "Log C" );
        } );

      // This code is executed immediately after firing off the inner FB.api method.
      console.log( "Log B" );
    }
  } );
```

If the above coding example finds 3 events then the console will show...

```
Log A
Log B
Log A
Log B
Log A
Log B
Log C
Log C
Log C
```

Does this help clarify any? This is basically a long way of saying you need to move your `console.log(myEvents[i][2]);` log inside of your 2nd closure.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `undefined` since you are not waiting for the `FB.api` call to complete. Since it is asynchronous event, it won't finish immediately. Because of this, `console.log(myEvents[i][2]);` will complete *BEFORE* the API call is complete and its values has been set.

You need to handle the async calls properly, then you will also get the correct value for the number of people attending.